# SOAP getLastRequest(), how to edit XML inside

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm doing a request in SOAP like this : `$xmlRequest = $client->__getLastRequest();` and I want to save the XML I'm getting in my database however it have Credit Card info and I want to remove that before saving. Is there a way to pass some arguments to `getLastRequest()` to remove some fields from the request or am I forced to loop through the XML and remove it?

What I want to do is as following:

```
<ccNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">XXXXXXXX</ccNumber>
```

to

```
<ccNumber xsi:type="xsd:string"></ccNumber>
```

Thanks

Comment: No! You have to process through the XML and remove what you want removed before storing it to the database

Comment: Unless there is an option on the call that generates this XML to tell the web service not to return the cc data. But only you can work that out as we dont know what service you are using

Comment: Thanks you, you are right